# Compiling C code with Redis on linux

Tags: c, linker, redis

How to correct following error when I compiled test code written in C using credis API:

```
 gcc -g -Wall -lcredis test_redis.c -o redisOUT

 /tmp/ccetckOb.o: In function `main':
 /home/faris/Downloads/credis-0.2.3/test_redis.c:12: undefined reference to `credis_connect'
 /home/faris/Downloads/credis-0.2.3/test_redis.c:15: undefined reference to `credis_ping'
 /home/faris/Downloads/credis-0.2.3/test_redis.c:18: undefined reference to `credis_set'
 /home/faris/Downloads/credis-0.2.3/test_redis.c:21: undefined reference to `credis_get'
 /home/faris/Downloads/credis-0.2.3/test_redis.c:25: undefined reference to `credis_close'

 collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Example on: http://code.google.com/p/credis/wiki/Examples

I'm busting my head for so long.

Thanks for solution.

Sam Iverish

Comment: Are you including the header file?

Comment: yes I have included credis.h

Answer (score 3):

Put the library *after* the source file that references it:

```
gcc -g -Wall test_redis.c -lcredis -o redisOUT
```

Comment: Thanks James. I got another issue, redis server is running with default settings. But when I call credis_connect(..) from C code, it returned NULL. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about Redis. You might want to open a new question.

Comment: why not using hiredis the official C client ? https://github.com/redis/hiredis , credis seen to be not maintened since 2 years